# Best way to iterate over rows and columns Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a GSheet with 57 columns and 11 rows (currently, this will increase daily).  I need to iterate all the rows and insert particular columns of data into a new sheet. One of the columns needs to be sliced as it stores an id as a string that I only need index [20:26] of.

My program needs to check that it is not duplicating data, and I am having trouble with the logic for this.  Below is what I have currently written and I'd be grateful for any pointers on how I iterate over all rows as they are added and only extract data from columns C:D:E:F etc.

```
function obtainUniqueId() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getSheet = sheet.getActiveSheet();
  var getRow = sheet.getDataRange();
  var columns = getRow.getNumColumns();
  var rows = getRow.getNumRows();
    for (var numColumn = 0; numColumn < columns; numColumn++){

      for(var numRow = 0; numRow < rows.length; numRow++){
        var cell = getRow.getCell(numRow);
          if(cell.isBlank()){
          cell.setValue(0);
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `Range#getValues` to perform a batch read of values. It is almost never a good idea to use `Range#getCell` (and the acceptability rapidly diminishes the more loops inside which you nest that call). You need to review the Apps Script "best practices" documentation as it covers how to read and write sheet values effectively.

Comment: Please share a copy/example of the sheet. What do you mean by "check that it is not duplicating data"? You want a different value in each cell of the spreadsheet?. Also, "insert particular columns of data into a new sheet.", which columns? which rows?

Comment: Essentially, we are collecting data daily from our clients. This will be input into a GSheet, what I need to do is ensure that when the code runs it doesn’t add lines of data previously added.  I hope that makes sense?